# How to use correctly Super Admin's role in Laravel Spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

As it's write in doc, i used Laravel's Gate::before() method.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // Implicitly grant "Super Admin" role all permissions
        // This works in the app by using gate-related functions like auth()->user->can() and @can()
        Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
            return $user->hasRole('Super Admin') ? true : null;
        });
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I had the role in middleaware groupe in web.php and it's work. The role 'Super Admin' dont have any permission.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api','role:Super Admin|Provider']], function() {
  ...
}
```

In my ProviderController

```
class ProviderController extends Controller
{
    function __construct(){
       
        $this->middleware('permission:provider-list|provider-create|provider-edit|provider-delete', ['only' => ['index','show']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:provider-create', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:provider-edit', ['only' => ['edit','update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:provider-delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
        
    }
```

My question it's the right way or not ? I thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your **User** model implements **HasRoles** trait?

Comment: Yes ! ```use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles```

Comment: what happens, if you change from Super Admin to super-admin? (with a dash)

Comment: In AuthServiceProvider and web.php ?

Comment: https://github.com/Bazsmagister/bicycle_7.7.1/blob/master/database/seeds/RolesAndPermissionsSeeder.php

Comment: yes. In web.php and in AuthServiceProvider also. maybe laravel looks for 'role:Super' and it couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

We use Spatie/laravel-permission often ([docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction)). Your code for checking if a user has a role is correct. Spatie's `hasRole` function does not care for spaces or dashes. The function does however care for whether the role actually exists. Ensure you [migrated](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/uuid#migrations) the right tables, and actually inserted the role into your database.

```
\Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::create([
  'name' => 'Super Admin',
  'guard_name' => 'web',
]);

$user->assignRole(\Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::findByName('Super Admin'));
```

Comment: I create the Super Admin's role
```
Role::find(1)
=> Spatie\Permission\Models\Role {#4168
     id: "1",
     name: "Super Admin",
     guard_name: "web",
     created_at: "2020-12-08 10:00:29.000000",
     updated_at: "2020-12-08 10:00:29.000000",
   }
```
And my user have the role

Comment: User::find(1)->roles

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4378
     all: [
       Spatie\Permission\Models\Role {#4130
         id: "1",
         name: "Super Admin",
         guard_name: "web",
         created_at: "2020-12-08 10:00:29.000000",
         updated_at: "2020-12-08 10:00:29.000000",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot {#3440
           model_id: "1",
           role_id: "1",
           model_type: "App\Models\User",
         },
       },

Comment: But, when i remove 'Super Admin' in Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api','role:Super Admin|Provider']], it's doesn't work. It's normal ?

Comment: @Zekura The middleware should not have any interference with whether the user has a role or not. If you just go to a normal controller (e.g. to return a view), and you `dd($user->hasRole('Super Admin')`, does it return `false`?

Comment: it's return true

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely that you only inserted the role for the `web` guard. You probably have it as the default guard, and that was the one inserted in your migration. The issue is that you are using the `api` guard to access that route. So you have to create the role for that guard too. I think they mention that in the Spatie documentation.